# Pointer casting offset of a class with single inheritance

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, polymorphism, language-lawyer

While learning the "Effective C++", I was firstly surprised when I learned the fact that if a class had multiple inheritance, its pointer may take offset when the pointer casting is done. Although it was not easy concept to grasp, but I think I managed to get it.

However, the author claims that this offset might happen even in the pointer casting of singly inherited class. I wonder what would be the such case, and wish to know the rationale behind it.

Comment: `a class pointer may take offset when the casting is done, and multiple inheritance is involved with the class` Please post a code example. What does it mean `pointer may take offset`? `when the casting is done` - what casting? What is casted? To which type, from which type? `multiple inheritance is involved` -  involved how?

Comment: @KamilCuk My apologies that my question was about some abstract concept in c++ programming. I considered adding some example for it, but the good answers with  concrete examples is already posted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can happen when polymorphism is introduced into a class hierarchy by a derived class.  Consider the following class:

```
struct Foo
{
    int a;
    int b;
};
```

This class is not polymorphic, and thus the implementation does not need to include a pointer to a virtual dispatch table (a commonly-used method of implementing virtual dispatch).  It will be laid out in memory like this:

```
  Foo
  +---+
a |   |
  +---+
b |   |
  +---+
```

Now consider a class that inherits from `Foo`:

```
struct Bar : Foo
{
    virtual ~Bar() = default;
};
```

This class *is* polymorphic, and so objects of this class need to include a pointer to a vtable so further derived classes can override `Bar`'s virtual member functions.  That means that `Bar` objects will be laid out in memory like this:

```
               Bar
               +---------+
vtable pointer |         |
               +---------+
 Foo subobject |   +---+ |
               | a |   | |
               |   +---+ |
               | b |   | |
               |   +---+ |
               +---------+
```

Since the object's `Foo` subobject is not at the beginning of the object, any `Foo*` initialized from a pointer to a `Bar` object will need to be adjusted by the size of a pointer so that it actually points at the `Bar` object's `Foo` subobject.

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6ad39f8aaeb080f5)

Answer (score 4):

```
class B {
  int a = 0;
};

class D : public B {
  virtual ~D() = default;
};
```

D has a virtual member. B does not. A common implementation of dynamic dispatch in C++ involves keeping a hidden pointer to a table of function addresses at the begining of the object.

This means the first byte of the B sub-object won't be at the start of the complete D object. A pointer cast would need to adjust the address by the vptr size.