# C++: Assigning derived class pointer to base class pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, c++17

Not very familiar with C++, so apologies for the potentially nooby question (though, I couldn't find an answer to this, despite semi-similar questions).

In a codebase I'm working on (sorry, can't share exact code), there's a Base class and a Derived class. I have a pointer to the derived class, `d`.

At some point, I set

```
Base* b = d;
```

What's super weird is that the pointers end up with different values! `b` ends up with an address exactly 8 greater than what `d` was.

I couldn't repro this with a straight-forward Base/Derived class, so I'm convinced there's something being done in the particular classes I'm working with.

Can anyone shed some light on how this can be possible? What in C++ might allow for something like this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think C++ has anything to do with the addresses

Comment: Sorry, you'll have to come up with more than that. Nothing that you've mentioned so far could be causing it, and if you've already created a minimal example that doesn't reproduce it, then there's clearly something else in your program having an effect. Assigning a pointer to a pointer is *never* going to alter the pointer's value in transmission.

Comment: Hi Silvio, that's really the answer I was looking for. As a novice C++ programmer, I just wanted confirmation that this shouldn't be happening, I guess. Feel free to add your comment as an answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pointer casting offset of a class with single inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63144389/pointer-casting-offset-of-a-class-with-single-inheritance)

Comment: Tip: copy your class definitions into a separate project, and dummy up what you need to make your one line compile. Then start removing class members. You should be able to get the definitions down to a few lines, short enough to change the names and present as a [mre] without sharing trade secrets. (My guess is that virtual inheritance is involved, just to be different than the people guessing virtual function tables.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's super weird is that the pointers end up with different values!

This is actually quite normal. `b` is a pointer to the base sub object. There's no guarantee that the base sub object is stored at the beginning of the enclosing derived object. In fact, it typically isn't if the class has virtual functions because language implementations typically store the virtual pointer there (virtual pointer is an implementation detail that a C++ programmer hardly ever really needs to know about).

Also consider multiple inheritance. If there are multiple non-empty bases, then surely they cannot all be stored at the same address.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer! My background is mostly in Java, so the concept of derived classes 'containing' base classes is foreign to me. Til :)

Comment: @KenKatagiri I may be wrong, but I would assume that Java also stores the base inside the derived object. Or maybe the derived object just contains a pointer that points to the base object. There's just no way to observe the difference between those implementation details in Java (again, I assume; I don't know Java in that much detail).

Comment: Ya, I guess java does the same under the hood and we're just shielded from those details.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of your question but basically, a pointer is used to point/store toward the address of the variable which is assigned to the pointer variable. To check the pointer value use *b, b, &b to check the value, address stored in the pointer, And that exact 8 is may be due the address of the dervied class